# UISearchBar crashing after filtering in Swift

Tags: swift, ios7, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I'm trying to make my app iOS 7 compatible with a search bar.  So that means I can't use `UISearchController` (like I would far prefer to be doing).  So I'm trying to implement the search bar with `searchDisplayController`.  But whenever I run the app and enter text into the search bar, the app crashes.

I plugged in a few break points to see when exactly this is happening, and it seems that it happens at the `numberOfRowsInSection` function.  Although I have no idea why that is because when I print to the console in this function, right before crash the filtered data array is what I would expect it to be given the input text in the status bar.

So here is my code.  Maybe I'm missing something.  A second set of eyes on this is greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

```
class RegData2: UITableViewController, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate {

    // Beginning to ios7 compatibility    


    let model = Model()
    var prevArray = [String]()
    var selectionPrev = String()
    var selection : String = ""
    var filteredTableData = [String]()
    var int = 0



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        // Reload the table
        self.tableView.reloadData()

    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController?.searchResultsTableView) {
            return self.filteredTableData.count
        }
        else {

            return prevArray.count

        }
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell!
        cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(18)


        if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController?.searchResultsTableView) {
            cell.textLabel?.text = filteredTableData[indexPath.row]
            return cell
        }
        else {

            cell.textLabel?.text = prevArray[indexPath.row]
            return cell
        }
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
    {
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
//        controller.searchBar.resignFirstResponder()

        if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController?.searchResultsTableView) {
            selection = filteredTableData[indexPath.row]
        }
        else {
            selection = prevArray[indexPath.row]
        }

        performSegueWithIdentifier("regData2ToRegView", sender: self)



    }


    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "regData2ToRegView" {

            let regView = segue.destinationViewController as! RegView
            regView.prevSelection = selection
            regView.prevSelectionType = selectionPrev


        }

    }


    func filterContentForSearchText(searchText: String, scope: String = "Title") {

        filteredTableData = prevArray.filter({( item : String) -> Bool in

            var match = (scope == "Title")
            var stringMatch = item.rangeOfString(searchText)

            return match && (stringMatch != nil)
        })
    }


    func searchDisplayController(controller: UISearchDisplayController, shouldReloadTableForSearchString searchString: String?) -> Bool {

        self.filterContentForSearchText(searchString!, scope: "Title")

        return true

    }

    func searchDisplayController(controller: UISearchDisplayController, shouldReloadTableForSearchScope searchOption: Int) -> Bool {
        self.filterContentForSearchText(self.searchDisplayController!.searchBar.text!, scope: "Title")

        return true

    }

}
```